# Microsoft docs for Dynamics 365 guide links to a webpage which results in "Runtime Error"

Tags: blogs, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, doc, server-error

Checking the guide/docs for Dynamics 365 while signed in from my work email(o365 business premium) at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/dev-tools/get-evaluation-copy

It opens up this page https://mbs.microsoft.com/customersource/global/AX/news-events/news/Microsoft_Dynamics_AX_Public_Preview which shows the message *"The content of this page is locked. To access this information log in to CustomerSource."*

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML0vR.png)

And clicking on **"CustomerSource"** opens up a page which is giving this 
 primitive server error:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnP3p.png)

It will be helpful if someone forwards it to somebody from Microsoft or they notice it!

Comment: I suggest you contact Microsoft about this. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue described can only be solved or answered by Microsoft and does not fit the scope of Stack Overflow (programming questions).

Comment: @FH-Inway Hm agree. Where should I contact microsoft about it?

Comment: @FH-Inway But someone may guide me regarding to the content/topic of that particular link. Wouldn't it be helpful for others facing the same issue?

Comment: If your company has access to customer source, they should have a contact at Microsoft which can handle this issue. You can also try the [Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations Forum](https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/f/765)

Answer (score 0):

Could have been a temporary issue. Please retry. Clicking on "CustomerSource" opens up a page as below:
https://mbs2.microsoft.com/ecsts/login?signin=03e2489ea2d8025aed8e8b5d7628c6e6
[Sign In Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLRJU.png)

Also first link open a page with the message, which is not an error just information -
The content of this page is locked.
To access this information log in to CustomerSource.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted an issue on github you can track here:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/dynamics-365-unified-operations-public/issues/1185